# XSLT ASCII text format

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to get file in ASCII Text format I am using below code

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="US-ASCII"/>
```

but it doesn't seem to be working any idea how can I make it work?

Comment: Be more precise: what does "it doesn't seem to be working" mean?

Comment: I'm curious about the motivation for the requirement for ASCII. Almost certainly, a downstream process that handles a file as XML would be able to use a document encoding of, say UTF-8, because every XML document is a sequence of Unicode characters. And, a downstream process that doesn't understand XML should be able to handle a binary file. What's your scenario?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, that your XSLT engine doesn't support `ASCII` for the `xml` output method and switches then automatically to `UTF-8` or `UTF-16`. You can try it with this minimal XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="US-ASCII"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>ä</root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you run it through your processor, e.g. Saxon:

```
$ saxonb-xslt -s:test.xsl -xsl:test.xsl
```

the result should look like this, if ASCII is supported:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<root>&#228;</root>
```

If that is not the case, you need a post-processing step. A reasonably recent version of [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) can do that:

```
xmllint --encode US-ASCII intermediate.xml > final.xml
```

Comment: Where does the spec say that only UTF-8 and UTF-16 are allowed? https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/#XML_ENCODING does not forbid other encodings.

Comment: Exactly at the place where I linked to, chapter 20 "Serialization". Note that the question is tagged `xslt-2.0`, so this is the relevant spec. Quote: "The default value is implementation-defined, but in the case of the `xml` and `xhtml` methods it MUST be either UTF-8 or UTF-16."

Comment: Actually, reading your link, it seems to me it says the exact same thing, provided that the specific implementation OP uses might not support ASCII.

Comment: The specs don't say that only UTF-8 and UTF-16 are allowed for the xml output method. The serialization spec only says that, for a not supported encoding, an implementation must raise an error or can fall back to those encodings. So far we do not know which implementation the poster uses and whether the "doesn't seem to be working" is meant to say that UTF-8 or 16 is used.

Comment: I agree with respect to the serialization spec, but XSLT 2 proper (my quote above) says rather unambiguously, that from `method=xml` follows necessarily, that `encoding=UTF(8|16)`, doesn't it?

Comment: No, it says that the default value must be UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Comment: @Boldewyn, yes, looks good and is a fine part of guessing what could have gone wrong for Manisha, now it is up the the poster of the question to explain in more detail how the original attempt failed.